# Split record into two records with a calculation based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

As title says, Let's say I have following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'UID':['A','B','C','D'],'FlagVal':[0,100,50,90],'TrueVal':[1000,1000,1000,1000]})
ndf = df.loc[~df['FlagVal'].between(0,100,inclusive='neither')]
mdf = df.loc[df['FlagVal'].between(0,100,inclusive='neither')]
```

I want to split records into two where FlagVal is between 0 and 100. i.e. mdf , and perform a few calculations -

```
def split_record(row):
    gtd = row.copy()
    ungtd = row.copy()
    gtd['UID'] = row['UID'] + '_T1'
    gtd['Flag'] = 'Y'
    ungtd['UID'] = row['UID'] + '_T2'
    ungtd['Flag'] = ''
    
    gtd['TrueVal'] = float(gtd['TrueVal'])*(float(gtd['FlagVal'])/100.0)
            
    ungtd['TrueVal'] = float(ungtd['TrueVal'])*(1 - (float(ungtd['FlagVal'])/100.0))
    
    gtd['FlagVal'] = 100
    ungtd['FlagVal'] = 0
    result_data = pd.DataFrame([gtd, ungtd])
    
    return result_data


split_df = pd.concat([split_record(row) for _, row in mdf.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)
```

then merge with 'ndf'. This works just fine for ~1000 records or so but it takes a toll when record count is in millions. I tried using apply function with axis=1, but not sure how to merge it with data again.

Can you point me to a correct function to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `split_df` in two steps (this will be very fast):

```py
# create the 100% part:
mdf_100 = pd.DataFrame({"TrueVal": mdf["FlagVal"].div(100) * mdf["TrueVal"]}).assign(
    FlagVal=100, UID=mdf["UID"] + "_T1", Flag="Y"
)

# create the 0% part:
mdf_0 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"TrueVal": (1 - mdf["FlagVal"].div(100)) * mdf["TrueVal"]}
).assign(FlagVal=0, UID=mdf["UID"] + "_T2", Flag="")

split_df = pd.concat([mdf_100, mdf_0]).sort_index()

print(split_df)
```

Prints:

```
   TrueVal  FlagVal   UID Flag
2    500.0      100  C_T1    Y
2    500.0        0  C_T2     
3    900.0      100  D_T1    Y
3    100.0        0  D_T2
```

---

EDIT: With multiple `TrueValX` columns:

```py
cols = ["TrueVal1", "TrueVal2", "TrueVal3"]

# create the 100% part:
mdf_100 = pd.DataFrame({c: mdf["FlagVal"].div(100) * mdf[c] for c in cols}).assign(
    FlagVal=100, UID=mdf["UID"] + "_T1", Flag="Y"
)

# create the 0% part:
mdf_0 = pd.DataFrame({c: (1 - mdf["FlagVal"].div(100)) * mdf[c] for c in cols}).assign(
    FlagVal=0, UID=mdf["UID"] + "_T2", Flag=""
)

split_df = pd.concat([mdf_100, mdf_0]).sort_index()

print(split_df)
```

Prints:

```
   TrueVal1  TrueVal2  TrueVal3  FlagVal   UID Flag
2     500.0    1000.0    1500.0      100  C_T1    Y
2     500.0    1000.0    1500.0        0  C_T2     
3     900.0    1800.0    2700.0      100  D_T1    Y
3     100.0     200.0     300.0        0  D_T2
```

Input `df`:

```
  UID  FlagVal  TrueVal1  TrueVal2  TrueVal3
0   A        0      1000      2000      3000
1   B      100      1000      2000      3000
2   C       50      1000      2000      3000
3   D       90      1000      2000      3000
```

Comment: Let's say I have about 20 different columns like TrueVal. how does the above logic work?

```
col_list = ['TrueVal1','TrueVal2','TrueVal3']
```

Comment: Only caveat in the above solution is, if dataframe column has space in its name, '''  FlagVal=0, UID=mdf["UID"] + "_T2", Flag="" ''' will not work. for the future reference, I suggest using a dictionary like object as , 

''' .assign(**{    "Flag VaL":0, "Unique ID": mdf["UID"] + "_T2", "Flag":"" }) '''

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_record_df(df):
    gtd = df.copy()
    ungtd = df.copy()
    gtd['UID'] = df['UID'] + '_T1'
    gtd['Flag'] = 'Y'
    ungtd['UID'] = df['UID'] + '_T2'
    ungtd['Flag'] = ''
    
    gtd['TrueVal'] = gtd['TrueVal']*(gtd['FlagVal']/100.0)
            
    ungtd['TrueVal'] = ungtd['TrueVal']*(1 - (ungtd['FlagVal']/100.0))
    
    gtd['FlagVal'] = 100
    ungtd['FlagVal'] = 0
    result_data = pd.concat([gtd, ungtd])
    
    return result_data

split_df = split_record_df(df)
```